Possible decays of a scalar particle, Feynman diagrams and calculation of branching ratio - Explenation of solution required
Consider the Lagrangian describing two Dirac fields of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ and a scalar neutral field of mass $M$, which in addition to the free terms contains the following interaction term
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_I=g(\bar{\psi}_2 \psi + \bar{\psi}_1 \psi_2)\phi.
\end{equation}
Considering that the first fermionic field $\psi_1$ describes electrons/positrons,
with mass $m_1=0.5$MeV, and the second one $\psi_2$ the muons/antimuons, with mass $m_2=100$MeV, while the scalar neutral
field $\phi$ describes an unknown neutral particle of mass $M = 1$TeV. Let the given interaction as the only one, are scalar particle decays in more than two particles possible? what are the Feynman diagrams describing the
relative amplitudes at the lowest order, and how much would you expect the relative Branching Ratio to be suppressed? (Only the order of magnitude of such suppression is required).
Question: Following is presented the solution of the problem, but onestly I didn't understand that. Why BR is related to coupling constant order and how can I tell the number of vertices in the diagram, could be potentially infinite? I would appreciate the explanation of the whole solution.
Solution:
Surely we cannot have a final state with another scalar particle, because of the kinematic limits of invariant mass conservation. The minimal way to have other particles is that, in the diagrams considered in 4. above, we add a vertex on one of the final fermionic legs from which a scalar line starts, which then with an additional vertex produces two more leptonic particles, so that we have $4$ in total. Such a process, which always involves tree diagrams, has two additional vertices, however, so their widths are suppressed by a factor of order $g^4=10^{-12}$, which is also the order of magnitude of the expected BR. It is interesting to ask whether there may not be additional factors that can substantially modulate the suppression factor. From the dimensional point of view, the width must still be the size of an energy and, in the limit to which the masses of the leptons are negligible, the only possibility is that it is always proportional to $M$, thus in total to $g^6M$. The only unknown is the dimensionless number factor, knowledge of which would require direct calculation.
